# Loading data to simulink (Invalid matrix-format)

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

When I'm trying load data, from Matlab to Simulink, I get this error:

```
 Error using TSFPnew (line 191)
    Invalid matrix-format variable specified as workspace input in 'modelTSFP/From Workspace5'. The matrix
    must have two dimensions and at least two columns. Complex signals of any data type and non-double
    real signals must be in structure format. The first column must contain time values and the remaining
    columns the data values.  Matrix values cannot be Inf or NaN.
```

I have very simple model (I know, it be easier to do this computation on Matlab, but this is only fragment of my model):

[image: model.slx]

All data have these same dimension 1x144:

[image: power]
[image: voltage]

Why I can't just load it to the Simulink space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the data in the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block represents a **time dependent variable** so if you are using an array, the first column of the array must be the time values and the second (or more) columns the corresponding data points. Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) for more details. Your data appears to be only vectors, where is the corresponding time data for your values?

If you want a **parameter** (that doesn't vary with time), then don't use a From Workspace block, use a [Constant](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/constant.html) block instead.